# CLLocationManger: Did update location is not being called

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, ios7.1

I am implementing location based application.In my application I am using the following methods.

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations


  -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

And the following is my code in ViewDidLoad

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}
```

Here my problem is didUpdateHeading method is being called but not didUpdateLocations.And I checked there is delete. Can any one help me out from this?

Answer (score 2):

You've called `startUpdatingHeading` so you get heading updates, you didn't call `startUpdatingLocation` so you don't get location updates.